# In gSoap, what does the "host" argument to soap_bind mean?

Tags: soap, gsoap

The gSoap API function `soap_bind` has an argument called `host`.  The documentation is unclear about what the argument is for.  Is it:

- The hostname/IP of a local network interface on which I want to listen
- The hostname/IP of the only remote host I will allow to connect
- Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: the hostname or IP address of the local interface you'll be listening on.

It corresponds to the traditional sockets bind (then listen, accept) sequence.