# How can I find out on what ethernet interface a gsoap server receives requests?

Tags: c++, gsoap

Is there a way to figure out on what ethernet interface and ip my gsoap server receives requests? I could not find a member of the soap context struct, that delivers this information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In gSoap, what does the "host" argument to soap\_bind mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1941019/in-gsoap-what-does-the-host-argument-to-soap-bind-mean)

Comment: No, I call `soap_bind(&soap , nullptr , HTTPS_PORT, BACKLOG)`. My interpretation of the documentation is, that I listen on all interfaces this way. But I would like to figure out, on which interface I receive a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the member `host` in the `struct soap` which provides the host ip.